# Swift protocol method usage

Tags: ios, methods, protocols, swift, xcode6

So I've started learning Swift, because it looks way better than ObjC. However I must be tired (its 2:37 AM here right now) because I cant see issue why Xcode screams I am trying to call undefined member. See the code below:

PeopleStackViewDataSource.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

protocol PeopleStackViewDataSource {

    func stackViewNumberOfItems(stackView: PeopleStackView) -> Int
    func stackViewGetView(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UIView
}
```

PeopleStackView.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class PeopleStackView: UIView {

    var datasource: PeopleStackViewDataSource? {
    didSet {
        self.redraw()
    }
    }

    var scaleDownBy: Double = 0.1

    init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

    }

    init(frame: CGRect, datasource: PeopleStackViewDataSource) {
        super.init(frame: frame);
        self.datasource = datasource;
    }

    func numberOfItems() -> Int {
        return self.datasource ? self.datasource.stackViewNumberOfItems(self) : 0
    }

    func redraw() {

    }


}
```

The issue is this line `return self.datasource ? self.datasource.stackViewNumberOfItems(self) : 0` where Xcode says that `stackViewNumberOfItems(self)`

> PeopleStackViewDataSource?' does not have a member named
>   'stackViewNumberOfItems

So, where is the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that

```
PeopleStackViewDataSource?' does not have a member named 'stackViewNumberOfItems
```

but `PeopleStackViewDataSource` does (notice the `?`)

You need to unwrap the optional `datasource`.

```
func numberOfItems() -> Int {
    if let ds = self.datasource {
        return ds.stackViewNumberOfItems(self)
    } else { return 0 }          
}
```

Comment: so what does the '?' mean actually?

Comment: it means it's an `Optional` of `PeopleStackViewDataSource`, i.e. a different type than `PeopleStackViewDataSource` alone. Read the official guide to know more about it.

Comment: so what would syntax look like for my check and return if i removed the '?'

Comment: you could just do `self.datasource.stackViewNumberOfItems(self)` but then `datasource` could never be `nil`.

Comment: Then leave it like that and simply unwrap the value at need as I showed in my answer.

Comment: ok, thats fine with me, but theres no way of writing that condition on a single line?

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't.

Comment: Try `return self.datasource ? self.datasource!.stackViewNumberOfItems(self) : 0`

Note the extra `!`